# Get the validation message for a specific component

Tags: validation, jsf, jakarta-ee

```
<h:inputText id="myInputText"
             title="The text from validation message here"
             style="#{component.valid? '' : 'border-color:red'}"
             validator="#{MyBean.validate}"
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="required"
             value="#{MyBean.value} />
<p:message for="myInputText" display="text"/>
```

Since I want to custom the looking for a failed validation in an inputText compoment and I know that it is possible to know whether the component was successfully validated or not, I would like to know if it is viable and how I can get the validation message, in order to display it as the tittle of my inputText component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you will have with what you're planning is that a single component can have more than one message queued. What are you going to do then? For demonstration purposes, you can use

```
<h:inputText id="myInputText"
             title="#{facesContext.getMessageList('myInputText').get(0)}"
             style="#{component.valid ? '' : 'border-color:red'}"
             validator="#{MyBean.validate}"
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="required"
             value="#{MyBean.value}" />
```

**EDIT :** You should just move the logic into your backing bean:

1. Implement a method that'll pull the detail from an available `FacesMessage` list, given a `clientId`

   ```
   public String getComponentMessageDetail(String clientId) {
       String detail = null;
       FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       List<FacesMessage> componentMessages = ctxt.getMessages(clientId);

       if (componentMessages != null && componentMessages.isEmpty() == false) {
           //returns the detail, from only the first message!
           detail = componentMessages.get(0).getDetail();
       }

       return detail;
   }
   ```
2. Use the utility method in your view

   ```
    <h:inputText id="myInputText"
                 title="#{MyBean.getComponentMessageDetail('myInputText')}"
                 style="#{component.valid ? '' : 'border-color:red'}"
                 validator="#{MyBean.validate}"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="required"
                 value="#{MyBean.value}" />
   ```

Comment: thank you for your time and answer. This approach can help me to reach the solution I want, however the return from your demonstration is one `FacesMessage` object, I want to show in my view the detail/summary from the message, not its id, you know how can I convert it?

Comment: At this point, it's probably best you just move all the logic to the backing bean, as it's just not tidy to do this much work in the view @unpix

Comment: Thanks @kolossus, stupid I didn't think to put the logic in the backing bean, always learning!

Btw, not `ctxt.getMessages(clientId)` but rather `ctxt.getMessageList(clientId);`

**However** do you know why I cannot access the getDetail method from my view?

Comment: @unpix - you should be able to `getDetail` in the view. Have you tried and failed? What happens when you try?

Comment: I got this in my tomcat log:

Property 'getDetail' not found on type javax.faces.application.FacesMessage

Answer (score 0):

How about this java method

```
public String getComponentMessageDetail(String cid){
  FacesContext ctxt  =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  Iterator<FacesMessage> cm = ctxt.getMessages(cid);
  List<String> msg = new ArrayList<>();
  while(cm.hasNext()) {
    msg.add(cm.next().getDetail());
  }
  return String.join(" | ", msg);
}
```

to show everything what's in the message cache?

Also in xhtml

```
<h:inputText id="myInputText" title="#{MyBean.getComponentMessageDetail('yourFormId:myInputText'}" style="#{component.valid? '' : 'border-color:red'}" validator="#{MyBean.validate}" required="true" requiredMessage="required" value="#{MyBean.value} />
```

it might be useful to put the name of your form-id in front of the input control's id. Otherwise the message list might have zero items, although there are some.

Here is another way to quickly show validation messages: [h:messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889481/see-error-in-primefaces-red-component)